# Python escape JSON file generated from Powershell output

Tags: python, json, powershell, encoding

I have a Powershell script that runs a SQL query, converts it to JSON using `ConvertTo-JSON` and writes it to a file. I then use the `Posh-SSH` powershell module to SFTP this file to a linux server.

The Linux server then runs a python script to open the file and convert it to JSON:

```
fname = '/foo/bar/map.json'
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    map = json.loads(f.read())
```

This Python script then throws the error:

> No JSON object could be decoded

This is due to Windows / Powershell throwing funky characters into the mix, apparently. I have used JSON linters to verify the integrity of the JSON, and when I copy the dump and paste it into a new file in Linux, it's all hunkydory.

How do I get around this? I don't know enough about character encoding to be able to tell what is happening.

Comment: Please include some of the file content (say, the first couple of lines, or several hundred characters if the lines are too long).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does writing a question on StackOverflow always make me solve my own problem right away? I mean, it's taken hours.

---

Setting the encoding to UTF8 did the trick.

```
Invoke-SQLCmd -Query "exec foo.dbo.proc"
   | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors
   | ConvertTo-Json
   | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) }
   | Out-File "c:\config\map.json" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: It's called, among other things, rubber duck debugging

Comment: I think it's like going to a colleague and telling him about your errors and coming back to your desk with the solution, without the colleague knowing how to turn on a computer... ;)